# How to output my recent tweets via twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm trying my first ever code project with Twitter4J (just for fun), in which it should show the five most recent tweets of my user timeline. I found this code online and have updated it with my personal data, but it keeps throwing this exception:

> 403: The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following). {"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]} Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at: http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=e5488403 TwitterException{exceptionCode=[e5488403-0cac370f], statusCode=403, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.5}

Any ideas on why it isn't working? I'm still very new to this and would love advice.

```
import twitter4j.Paging;
import twitter4j.ResponseList;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.*;

public final class ReadTweets {

/**
 * Main method.
 *
 * @param args
 *            the command line arguments; unused here
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    //consumer key and consumer secret
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("---", "---");
    //access token and access token secret
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken("---", "---"));

    try {
        ResponseList<Status> a = twitter.getHomeTimeline(new Paging(1,5));
        for (Status b : a) {
            System.out.println(b.getText());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add http.useSSL=true at twitter4j.properties
or upgrade your twitter4j to latest version.
using ConfigurationBuilder

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(YOURCONSUMER_KEY);
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(YOURCONSUMER_SECRET);
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(YOURACCESSTOKEN);
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(YOURTOKENSECRET);
    configurationBuilder.setUseSSL(true);
    Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();
    try {
        ResponseList<Status> a = twitter.getHomeTimeline(new Paging(1, 5));
        for (Status b : a) {
            System.out.println(b.getText());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do i find that?

Comment: I you didn't use twitter4j.properties, you can use ConfigurationBuilder to configure programmatically. I've updated my answer with sample code